# Out of range error on SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

I'm using a `SqlDataReader` and get this exception when trying to read a column...

> *System.IndexOutOfRangeException: record*

Here is the code...

```
SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(PART_NO)) AS PART_NO, record AS CUSTOMER_NO FROM [RMAData].[dbo].[IMPORTING_ORDER_EDI] WHERE sessionID = '" + Session.SessionID + "'", connection);
SqlDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
   while (reader.Read())
   {
       lblWebMasterMessage.Text += "record " + reader["record"].ToString() + "<br />";
...
```

If I change the `lblWebMasterMessage.Text` to the following it works just fine...

```
lblWebMasterMessage.Text += "record " + reader["PART_NO"].ToString() + "<br />";
```

The difference between record and `PART_NO` in the SQL Server table is that 'record' is a primary key and an `int`, `PART_NO` is a `varchar(100)`.

The trouble is, I need the 'record' to identify the record to update it later...

I really can't see why it can return one field and not the other?

Comment: Stuart I would recommend that you read up on `SQL Aliasing` when ever you use the `AS` key word that's the field that you need to reference in your results set not the actual name that's in the Database itself

Comment: i know about sql aliasing... this was a daft mistake that i just couldn't see. woods and trees and all that!!

Comment: Not a problem Stuart I guess I could see that.. I was just offering an opinion no harm no foul

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you have no field named "record", you aliased it to "CUSTOMER_NO" so change the code to:

```
lblWebMasterMessage.Text += "record " + reader["CUSTOMER_NO"].ToString() + "<br />";
```

That said, you can also use index instead of name so to read the second column:

```
lblWebMasterMessage.Text += "record " + reader[1] + "<br />";
```

Comment: I'd warn against using the index to reference columns because changes to the SQL Statement can result in unexpected behavior if you forget to change the index.

Comment: @Michael true but on the other hand, changing the alias name will lead to the error our OP here faced when using name to reference the column.

Comment: ahh.... i am sorry! i didn't see that!! why did i do that?! i wish people at work would leave me alone so i can concentrate properly and stop wasting peoples time with my daft mistakes!!

THANK YOU!! :)

Comment: Michael you are close that would only pertain if you were to reference the Column based on the `reader[1].ToString()` for example because the column lengths may change but if you are doing it by `Column Nae` you would never find this to be an issue

Answer (score 2):

In my case this error was because I was accidentally executing two select statements in my command text. I had two separate output results and the first output didn't contain the column name I was reading and hence the error.